# how to fetch the objects which has no related (via a specific relationship) entities.

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I want to fetch all the objects from an entity which has no related objects (using a specific key path)
I'm thinking about using count, but dont know how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following search predicate if it is a 1:1 relationship:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relationshipName = NULL"];
```

and for 1:n relationships:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relationshipName.@count == 0"]
```